# CoreLocation get latitude and longitude at a certain distance and direction from coordinate

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-location

I'm trying to determine the location that is a certain distance and heading from another location.  I am using latitude,longitude from CoreLocation in iOS.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure how to answer this.  I've been reading iOS SDK docs all day.  I've also read this  http://janmatuschek.de/LatitudeLongitudeBoundingCoordinates  which was linked from another question.   Sor far, I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lat2 = asin(sin(lat1)*cos(d/R) + cos(lat1)*sin(d/R)*cos(θ))
lon2 = lon1 + atan2(sin(θ)*sin(d/R)*cos(lat1), cos(d/R)−sin(lat1)*sin(lat2))
```

`R` is Earth's radius in your preferred units. (6371 in km)

Comment: Could you please elaborate.  What are d and R?  I presume R is radius of the sphere.    Where do I apply the direction I wish to measure from point 1?    EDIT:  I googled the formula and found this webpage http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: `d` is the distance traveled. `θ` is the heading.